# List and BinarySearch index not every correct

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

i have some problem again about list and binarysearch. In general, i have:

```
type
  TMyArr = array [1..5] of Integer;    

  PMyList = record
    Comb: TMyArr;
    ... // other fields    
  end;
  TMyList = TList<PMyList>;

var 
  MyArr: TMyArr; 
  MyList: TMyList;  
  rMyList: PMyList;
```

i load value in array MyArr and want find element MyArr (with all values in it) in list TMyList, then i use:

```
rMyList.Comb := MyArr;
MyList.BinarySearch(rMyList, iIndex3, TDelegatedComparer<PMyList>.Construct(Compare));
```

with Compare so defined:

```
function CompareInt(const Left, Right: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if Left < Right then
    Result := -1
  else if Left > Right then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

function Compare(const Left, Right: PMyList): Integer;
begin
  Result := CompareInt(Left.Comb[1], Right.Comb[1]);
  if Result = 0  then
    Result := CompareInt(Left.Comb[2], Right.Comb[2]);
  if Result = 0  then
    Result := CompareInt(Left.Comb[3], Right.Comb[3]);
  if Result = 0  then
    Result := CompareInt(Left.Comb[4], Right.Comb[4]);
  if Result = 0  then
    Result := CompareInt(Left.Comb[5], Right.Comb[5]);
end;
```

Now, my problem is that not every result is correct. In sense that often i have correct index of element and other time i have other index corresponding to other element, in casual.
As i can solve it? Where i have mistake?
I want only find index corresponding of MyArr in TMyArr.
Thanks again very much.

Answer (score 4):

Your `Compare` function is just fine. If the binary search fails to work correctly then that can only be because the list is not ordered by the order defined by `Compare`. Call the `Sort` function on the list once you have finished populating, and before you start searching. When you call `Sort`, you must make sure that it use *your* compare function.

Comment: @Marcello Does this answer your question?